# Making a 2D array a property, JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

How am I suppouse to add a 2D array to my properties and constructor. I'm suppouse to have an object Sea, which is a 2D array of Strings and a constructor which takes the x and y coordinates. But where am I suppouse to initialize the array. In the constructor or outside of it?

```
package battleship;

public class Sea {

//declare properties
private int width;
private int lenght;
private String[][] field = new String[getLenght()][getWidth()];

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public int getLenght() {
    return lenght;
} 
public String[][] getField() {
    return field;
}


//create constructor
public Sea(int width, int length){
    this.width = width;
    this.lenght = length;
    field =  new String[length][width];
}

//creates a method that visualizes the field with the ships
String[][] toStringWithShips(){
    for(int col = 0; col < this.getLenght(); col++){
        for(int row = 0; row < this.getWidth(); row++){
            field[col][row] = ".";
        }
    }
    return field;
}
}
```

Comment: I guess you must initialise height and width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare the array outside the constructor, initialize it in the constructor

```
...
String[][] field;

...
public Sea(int width, int length){
    field = new String[width][length];
     ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1: 
If it has predefined values it can be populated in the constructor, Or else if user inputs needs to be taken directly call toStringWithShips() with those values. Also, create a getter method to get the 2D array by any other method.

Approach 2: 
Create Setter method to populate the values for the 2 D array. create a getter method to retrieve those values.

Answer (score 0):

If the x and y values are given in the ctor then you can init the array there but I think it depands on your app, if the array will certainly be in use and you benefit from the initial construction then I would recommend on initialization in the ctor, if its mot the case I would consider having a dynamic init in the getter

Answer (score 0):

Always intialisation of object creation should be done through constructor itself , So it is better to use constructor for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

If I get your Question right, You can also create another constructor which is a 2-D array of String like so:--

```
public Sea(String [][] field){
   this.field = field
}
```

But you can also give more explanation on what you really want to acheive